# How to import OpenCV in the Maven project? (Intellij Idea)

Tags: java, maven, opencv, intellij-idea

I need to import OpenCV to my project.
I downloaded library from https://opencv.org/releases version 4.5.5.
Extracted and then I added .jar and .dll file to Project Structure but it doesn't work.

[Project Structure in Intellij Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWoNn.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>OpenCvTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5-1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

OpenCvExample.java

```
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class OpenCvExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println("mat = " + mat.dump());
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Bartek\Downloads\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java455.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.load(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries$NativeLibraryImpl.open(NativeLibraries.java:388)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:232)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.findFromPaths(NativeLibraries.java:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.NativeLibraries.loadLibrary(NativeLibraries.java:287)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2422)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:818)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1989)
    at OpenCvExample.main(OpenCvExample.java:8)
```

Comment: Is file present here `C:\Users\Bartek\Downloads\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java455.dll` ?

Comment: Yes, it is present